# Decoding problems with fitz (PyMuPdf)

Tags: python, macos

I have a decoding problem with fitz.Document in Python 3.7.

I'm getting a string of unrecognisable characters when calling `getText()` on a page of a PDF document.

The code I'm using is

```
import fitz

pdf_reader = fitz.open(input_file)
# Extract the text from the first page
page_content = pdf_reader[0].get_text("text")
```

this is the string I get (with lot's of strange characters - `chr(65533)`):
`'���������������������\nu\nv\n�������������������������������������������������������������������������\n����������������������������������������������������������������������������\n����������������������������������������\ns\nt\nu\nv\ns\nt\n�������������������������\n����������������\n�������������\n������������\n������������������������������\n��������\n����������\n�����\n�\n�������������\n��������������������������� ����������\n�������������������� ���������� ����������\n������������������������������������������������\n����������� ����������\n��������� ����������\n����������������������������\n \n������������\n�\n�������\n������������������������������������������\n�����������������������������\n��������\n�������\n�����\n��������������������������������������\n��������\n�������\n�����\n�����������������������������\n��������\n�������\n�����\n������������������������������\n��������\n������\n�����\n�������������\n��������\n��������\n������������������������������������������\n������������������������\n��������\n�����\n�����\n�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������\n������������������������������������������������������������\n��������������\n�������\n������������\n�����������������������������������������\n������������������\n��������\n�����\n�����\n�������������\n��������\n�������\n�����\n������������������\n�������\n�\n������������������\n��������\n����\n����\n������������������\n������������\n������\n��������\n�������\n�\n���������\n�������\n��������������\n���������\n���������������\n����������������������������������������������\n�������\n���������������������\n��������������������������������������������������������������������������\nEmitido por programa certificado nº 2386/AT. Este documento não serve de fatura.\n'`
.

I can open the document without any error in Acrobat Reader and other pdf readers, and I can select the text and copy-paste it.
This is an extract of the copy-paste:

`Pág.1/3 ¤ ¥ A falta de pagamento ou o pagamento depois do prazo limite, pode implicar custos adicionais e a suspensão do serviço. Pode também originar o pagamento de uma caução ou o agravamento da mesma. ¢ £ ¤ ¥ ¢ £ Modalidades de Pagamento: · Débito Direto · Multibanco · Lojas MEO · Pontos de Venda Autorizados · Cheque · Pay Shop . CTT OS SEUS MEOS: Os seus MEOS em 14/07/2023: 1304 Detalhe da Fatura Nº A795979751 julho 2023 Este documento não é válido para efeitos fiscais Nº Cliente: 1290600729 Nº Conta: 1339848861 Data de Emissão: 14 jul 2023 MENSALIDADES PACOTES Nº Serviço 1702361504 · Vila Nova de Gaia Desconto Mensalidade Camp.Emp jul 2023 - 3,250 23,00 Desconto mensalidade fatura eletrónica jul 2023 - 0,813 23,00 Desconto Mensalidade Camp.Emp jul 2023 - 1,223 23,00 M4 (TV+NET 200+VOZ+MÓVEL 10GB) jul 2023 53,000 23,00 Total Pacotes € 47,714 TELEFONE...`

What might be the problem or solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you posted is not handled well by MuPDf  (Posibly was an Adobe perfect file, but most recently processed by "**I Love** rewriting **PDF**s"!), and here is similar output from MuTool convert. I have removed the \n line feeds to keep the snip small, but you should see a similar pattern to start of your bigger snip.

```
��������������������� u v
�������������������������������������������������������������������������
����������������������������������������������������������������������������
����������������������������������������
 s t  u v  s t
```

The normal solution would be to "Re-Print" from Acrobat or Chrome to a new PDF. However, both my Acrobat and Chrome refused to Print or print as blank, even though either could save core data as plain text!

```
Pág.1/3

OS SEUS MEOS:

Os seus MEOS em 14/07/2023: 1304

Detalhe da Fatura Nº A795979751 julho 2023

Este documento não é válido para efeitos fiscais

Nº Cliente: 1290600729 Nº Conta: 1339848861 Data de Emissão: 14 jul 2023

Emitido por programa certificado nº 2386/AT. Este documento não serve de fatura.
...
```

*section removed for reduced size of paste*

```
...
 Vila Nova de Gaia MEOBox DVR Full HD Oferta MEOBox jul 2023 jul 2023 2,431 - 2,431 23,00 23,00 Total Equipamentos € 0,000

Total Mensalidades € 47,714 IVA Taxa Base de Incidência Valor do IVA 23,00% € 47,714 € 10,97

Total IVA € 10,97

Arredondamento € - 0,004

TOTAL DA FATURA O valor foi arredondado para cêntimos de euro. € 58,68 Informação Adicional

Período de fidelização a decorrer no serviço 1702361504 , até 03 jun 2024.
```

If we look at the file in an editor, we can see there isn't any valid text other than characters used for the surface graphics like the U and V:

[image]

Hence the best solution would be to open the file for copy and paste in any reader that can manage to unscramble the input.

One possibility is the MuTools sister application [Ghostscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostscript) where we can try a fix (simple I/O)

```
fix problem.pdf
>gswin32c.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o output.pdf "problem.pdf"

GPL Ghostscript 10.01.1 (2023-03-27)
Copyright (C) 2023 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
Loading font C0T05590 (or substitute) from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Regular

The following warnings were encountered at least once while processing this file:
        encountered more q than Q

   **** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
   **** The file was produced by:
   **** >>>> iLovePDF <<<<
   **** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
   **** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
   **** specification.
```

However, even after that, Acrobat still refused to reprint its own file.
I have to say it is not a good prospect apart from using the Clipboard, or Acrobat text output.

One alternative is use command line tools/API to extract the PDF content and then batch file filter for plain text.

[image]

Comment: is there a way whether to understand if a PDF has a problem like that?

Comment: ok, but is there a way to check the problem with Python code?